# Can results of ARRAYFORMULA be used as values in an annotated timeline?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to create an annotated timeline with the following data, which exists on another sheet:

[image: My sample data]

I am using an `ARRAYFORMULA` to retrieve the text. I want to display these values as an annotated timeline chart, but I keep getting this error:

> Each values column may be followed by one or two annotation columns. column number 1 is of type string

[image: The error I am getting]

I have tried

- (Select Column) `Format->Number->Date` and
- (Select Column)`Data->Data Validation->Must be valid date`

It is driving me nuts. Is it because it is an `ARRAYFORMULA`? If I hand type it out again (which is simply untenable) the chart generates fine. Is there a fix, or is this just broken?

Google Sheets link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sIEgWVPLrNWYImCIlWS8gvj8JQIe-cB4P2grlHW0ysk/edit?usp=sharing

On "Sheet20", you will see the failing version, and if you scroll right you will see the identical hand typed data on a working version.

Comment: your issue is in column B arrayformula formating, not in array of A column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can, but the whole array needs to be converted back into **`VALUE()`**

**B1:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Patches!B1:B1000, ".", "", 2)), ))`**

[image: 3]

Comment: Can you explain what was causing this? I don't understand what you mean by `back into __VALUE ()__`. Did I accidentally convert something or was it a byproduct of __ARRAYFORMULA ()__?

Comment: @TylerGubala your formal formula in Sheet20!B1 was =ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(Patches!B1:B1000, ".", "", 2))

Comment: @TylerGubala if you want to create annotated timeline chart the 2nd column needs to have number (numeric) values. array you imported from Patches!B1:B was in text format so timeline chart resulted in error you mentioned. you can test it with =isnumber(Patches!b1) and =isnumber(Sheet20!b1). first is FALSE 2nd is TRUE (because array was re-formated from text into values). so to answer your question: its not byproduct of arrayformula. and it was caused by not converting B column (imported data due array) into values

Comment: Okay... guess I was just using __ARRAYFORMULA()__ wrong then...? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @TylerGubala I wouldn't say "wrong"... just in this case you forgot the middle step to convert array into array with values

Comment: That makes much more sense now. Thank you for the clarification.